# Why is this getLastRow statement not working?

Tags: google-apps-script

Noob problem, and noob question. I've got 4 eyes, and none work, because I can't see where the problem is...

I'm starting on building a mileage logging app in google sheets. An important part of this is putting the correct information in the correct cell. I've got the start of a script, and I'm already running into problems. My log sheet (named 'Mileage Log') has 1 row of headers. The data starts on row 2. When I run my script, it gives me lastRow = 4. Why?

Here's what I'm using:

```
    // Get the 'Mileage Log' spreadsheet and sheet
      var logSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1PR3pK55urtYY9mnJTb_1Iacys0tj2lGd88CEfrhBIjs');
      var logSht = logSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
      
      // Determine the last used row in the "Mileage Log" spreadsheet
      var lastRowLogSht = logSht.getLastRow();
      Logger.log("The value of 'lastRowLogSht' is: " + lastRowLogSht);
}
```

(Apologies if this did not post over properly)

Does anybody have any idea what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: `getLastRow()` Returns the position of the last row that has content, not the values of the last row. Is that the confusion? Or is it that there's data beyond row 4? (Source: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow() )

Comment: There is no content after row 2. Actually, while I was waiting on your answer, I went to my Log Sheet, and deleted row 3 and beyond. I ran my script again. The sheet in question now had 2 rows. All of the rows now had content. My Logger.log statement returned 4. Why?

Comment: Discovered the problem!

Comment: Do you mind posting it as an answer, in case someone else has the same issue? @user3279926